# How How to add annotations to plots AND keep the boxes on the top (by ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add annotations to each plot, but when I use `tag_facet()` the grey box on top of plots disappears. How to add annotations to plots AND keep the boxes on the top?

Thanks for any help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, please provide the code you are using so far and a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for `egg::tag_facet()` from [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/egg/src/R/tag_facet.r) is:

```
tag_facet <- function(p, open = "(", close = ")", tag_pool = letters, x = -Inf, y = Inf, 
                      hjust = -0.5, vjust = 1.5, fontface = 2, family = "", ...) {
  
  gb <- ggplot_build(p)
  lay <- gb$layout$layout
  tags <- cbind(lay, label = paste0(open, tag_pool[lay$PANEL], close), x = x, y = y)
  p + geom_text(data = tags, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", label = "label"), ..., hjust = hjust, 
                vjust = vjust, fontface = fontface, family = family, inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
                theme(strip.text = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank())
}
```

you could alternatively define a function that doesn't change the theme as:

```
tag_facet2 <- function(p, open = "(", close = ")", tag_pool = letters, x = -Inf, y = Inf, 
                      hjust = -0.5, vjust = 1.5, fontface = 2, family = "", ...) {
  
  gb <- ggplot_build(p)
  lay <- gb$layout$layout
  tags <- cbind(lay, label = paste0(open, tag_pool[lay$PANEL], close), x = x, y = y)
  p + geom_text(data = tags, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", label = "label"), ..., hjust = hjust, 
                vjust = vjust, fontface = fontface, family = family, inherit.aes = FALSE)
}
```